# aws authorization: how to get programmatic authorization access to S3 (any service) from external service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, aws-sts

I'd like to know how to get a temporary "access token" to get access to aws S3.

I'm developing a service needs access to S3, but this access has to be authorized by an user. For example:

As a `my-service` user, I'd like to configure S3 storage provider into `my-service`. I mean, user wants `my-service` get access to S3.

From non-aws world, the first thing comes me in mind is to use some mechanism similar to OAuth2, but inside aws world, I don't know how to delegate access to `my-service`.

I've took a look on STS, but I don't quite figure out how to play correctly with it.

The flow would be:

1. Receive events when a new file is created or updated or deleted on S3.
2. For each event handle it and get properties...

Currently, I'm only interested on how to delegate authorization to `my-service` to get file properties, or whichever action once event is received.

Please note I'm asking for programmatic access, not console access.

My `myservice` is running outside Aws infrastructure.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you need this access for? Maybe [presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) can be helpful if it is something simple?

Comment: I've added some details on post. Straightforwardly, I need to first receive events on `my-service` and then for each S3 action get file properties,...